# Proving pointwise convergence of a function sequence by definition

Tags: proof-writing, dirac-delta, pointwise-convergence

I'm writing a school paper about convergence. I am a bit stuck on proving pointwise convergence by definition for a particular function sequence related to the delta function:

Let $T_n(x)$ be a function sequence defined on a closed interval $[0,1]$ with following properties:
$$\text{1.} \ T_n(x) \geq 0, \ T_n \ \text{is continuous.}$$
$$\text{2.} \ \lim_{n\to\infty} \operatorname{supp} (T_n) = \{0\}.$$
$$ \text{3.} \ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} T_n = 1. $$

It is fairly obvious (I think) that this sequence does converge pointwise to $0$, and I have actually proven it by definition with my teacher a week ago and understood the proof well, but now I'm hardstuck on recreating it for some reason.

To be precise, I need the proof by this kind of definition:

Let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of functions defined on a metric space $X$. Then  ${f_n}$ converges pointwise to a function limit $f$ if and only if $$ \forall  \ x \in X, \ \forall \ \epsilon > 0, \ \exists \ M > 0 $$
$$ \text{such that} \  |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon \ \text{when} \ n > M.$$

I would appreciate a hint, a starting point (mostly can't determine which property of the function sequence I've defined can be translated into the $\epsilon$, $M$, $x$, $n$ world) or a complete proof. I already have a decent grasp of proving pointwise convergence for function sequences that are defined explicitly (by a formula).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How is the limit of sets $\lim_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{supp} (T_n) = \{ 0\}$ defined for you? I guess this is the point you need to start at, throwing in continuity at some point.

Comment: In order to solve this in a mathematically correct way, you would have to define a function space, in which you are looking for your solution and your $T_n$. For example: You said your $T_n$ are continous. Therefore you could take the continous Functionspace $C^0(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ but your function does not converge in this space. You could then take kind of the Space of all functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$, with a fitting metric. Then your solution would be $\infty$ in $0$ and $0$ everywhere else. If you take $L_1$ the solution would be the 0-Function.

Comment: If you realy want convergence to the dirac distribution, you would have to take another convergence definition and you would have to take some kind of space of distributions.